# WordPress/WooCommerce website stops responding when options table gets big

Tags: database, wordpress, web, woocommerce

The below strange incident suddenly started happening:

I have a website built with WordPress/WooCommerce. It's database it's quite big (800MB currently), but this is normal due to the big number of orders (30,000 currently).

Lately i've noticed that the website stops responding, and after a lot of debugging and research i've noticed that the website comes back if i delete all transients from the options table (using => DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('%_transient_%')
). The last time that occured, options table was 74MB. I am not sure if it the table size that matters or the number of rows. I took a screenshot of the table when website was down => https://prnt.sc/1a7zstq

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe cron isn’t running successfully on your server? Otherwise, most transients have a prefix in their name to help figure out what is making them. Find the most commonly used prefix in the database and you’ll need to debug from there. Most likely an overzealous plugin trying to cache something incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not mind transients to be created. I understand that those are essentials. The thing is why everything becomes unresponsive at some point. What causes that?

Comment: What I'm saying is that I think you might have a rogue hook/script that is creating too many transients. Transients actually aren't essential to WordPress, they are just a form of caching. Code that is written properly to interact with the transients should work 100% if they are immediately deleted. I still would recommend performing a scan of the transients and look for what you have the most of. Sometimes it is the results of API/HTTP calls, so you could also have several hundred 1MB transients.